# Metric spaces and ultrafilters

Tags: metric-spaces, filters, hausdorff-distance, gromov-hausdorff-limit

Assume $X_n$ are proper metric spaces and $X$ is a compact metric space.

Fix an non-principal ultrafilter $\omega$ on $\mathbb{N}$.

Assume we have a metric space $\mathbb{X}$ such that:

(1) $\mathbb{X}=X\coprod X_1\coprod X_2\coprod...$

(2) For each $j=1,2,3,...$ the canonical injection $i_j:X_j\rightarrow \mathbb{X}$ is distance preserving.

(3) The canonical injection $i:X\rightarrow \mathbb{X}$ is distance preserving.

(4) Each $X_1,X_2,...$, is open in $\mathbb{X}$.

(5) For each $x\in \mathbb{X}$, $dist(x,X_n)\rightarrow dist(x,X)$.

Let $x_1,x_2,....$ where $x_n\in X_n$. Why does it follow that the $\omega-limit$ of that sequence exists and is in $X$?

Comments:

- Clearly $(x_n)_n$ is in $\mathbb{X}$.
- It is not true that for large enough $n$, $x_n\in X$ (by disjointness).
- In compact metric space, the $\omega$-limit for any sequence in $X$ exists and is unique.
- Proper metric spaces are complete.

Comment: I don't think this is true--condition (5) is too weak.  What Gromov-Hausdorff convergence actually gives you is the stronger condition that $X_n$ converges to $X$ in the Hausdorff metric of $\mathbb{X}$.

Comment: @EricWofsey Condition (5) is defined to be Hausdorff convergence: See page 52 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.08539.pdf for the definition of Hausdorff convergence and the proof of part (a) of theorem 5.16 (which is essentially what i'm not understanding). I presumed that  condition (5) is equivalent to Hausdorff convergence, as defined in terms of tubular neighborhoods.

Comment: @EricWofsey I would be content with an answer to my problem upon replacing condition (5) with the definition of Hausdorff convergence (in the sense defined in my preceding comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true.  For a counterexample, consider $X_n=\mathbb{R}\times\{1/n\}$ and $X=[0,1]\times\{0\}$.  Give $\mathbb{X}$ the following metric: the distance between two points is the shortest path between them where you are allowed to move horizontally in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and vertically only within $[0,1]\times\mathbb{R}$.  So restricted to $[0,1]\times\mathbb{R}$ this is the $\ell^1$ metric, but for instance $d((2,1),(2,1/2))=5/2$ since you have to first move from $(2,1)$ to $(1,1)$ and then down to $(1,1/2)$ and then back out to $(2,1/2)$.  This satisfies all your assumptions, but the sequence $x_n=(2,1/n)$ has no accumulation point in $\mathbb{X}$.

To make this true you need to strengthen (5) to say that $X_n$ converges to $X$ with respect to the Hausdorff metric of $\mathbb{X}$.  With that assumption, for each $n$ we can pick a point $y_n\in X$ such that $d(x_n,y_n)\leq d_H(X_n,X)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.  By compactness of $X$, $(y_n)$ converges to some $x\in X$ with respect to $\omega$, and then it follows that $(x_n)$ converges to $x$ with respect to $\omega$ as well.

Comment: Thanks! Upvoted. Much appreciated